# Regex get string follow certain words

Tags: python, regex

From this text

```
1. @aut1.or
@Autowired
2. @Override
@param
@SuppressWarnings
```

I would like to take `[1. @aut1.or\n@Autowired , 2. @Override\n@param\n@SuppressWarnings]`

I have code:

```
import re

txt ='''1. @aut1.or
@Autowired
2. @Override
@param
@SuppressWarnings'''

x = re.findall("(?:[0-9][.][ ]).+", txt)
print(x)
```

This gives `['1. @aut1.or', '2. @Override']`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this help you

```
import re

txt ='''1. @aut1.or @Autowired 2. @Override @param @SuppressWarnings'''

list_match = re.findall(r'(\d+. @\w+.\w+)|(@\w+)', txt)
result = []
for i in list_match:
    if i[0]:
        result.append(i[0])
    else:
        result[-1] += '\n' + i[1]
// ['1. @aut1.or\n@Autowired', '2. @Override\n@param\n@SuppressWarnings']
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use this regex:

```
^\s*(\d+\..*?)(?=\n\s*\d+\.|\Z)
```

which matches:

- `^` : beginning of line
- `\s*` : some whitespace
- `\d+\.` : some digits, followed by a period `.`
- `.*?` : a minimal number of characters
- `(?=\n\s*\d+\.|\Z)` : a lookahead for either:

  - `\n\s*` : a newline followed by some whitespace
  - `\d+\.` : digits and a period; **or**
  - `\Z` : the end of the string

You need to use this with the [`M`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.M) (multi-line) and [`S`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.S) (dot-all) flags.

Regex demo on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/XywQ19/1)

In python:

```py
import re

txt ='''1. @aut1.or
@Autowired
  2. @Override
@param
@SuppressWarnings'''

x = re.findall(r'^\s*(\d+\..*?)(?=\n\s*\d+\.|\Z)', txt, re.S | re.M)
```

Output:

```
[
  '1. @aut1.or\n@Autowired',
  '2. @Override\n@param\n@SuppressWarnings'
]
```

Comment: Thank a lot! It's useful to me.

Comment: However, when I add some space before "   2." It crashed. I edited code to x = re.findall(r'^\s*\d+\..*?(?=\n\d+\.|\Z)', txt, re.S | re.M). it din't work right.

Comment: Do you mean the `2.` does not start at the beginning of the line?

Comment: @NguyenNgoc please see my edit; I think that should address your issues

Comment: Your edit addressed my issues. Thank you so much. @Nick

Comment: @NguyenNgoc good to hear. I'm glad I could help

Answer (score 1):

You might also first match digits followed by a dot, and then all lines starting with an `@` char.

```
^\s*(\d+\..*(?:\n@.*)+)
```

The pattern matches:

- `^\s*` Start of string followed by optional whitespace chars
- `(` Capture **group 1** (which will be returned by re.findall)

  - `\d+\.` Match 1+ digits and a dot
  - `.*` Match the rest of the line
  - `(?:\n@.*)+` Repeat 1+ times matching a newline, @ char and the
    rest of the line
- `)` Close group 1

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/56R4Dy/1) and [Python demo](https://ideone.com/v6LFv8)

```
import re

txt ='''1. @aut1.or
@Autowired
2. @Override
@param
@SuppressWarnings'''

x = re.findall(r"^\s*(\d+\..*(?:\n@.*)+)", txt, re.M)
print(x)
```

Output

```
['1. @aut1.or\n@Autowired', '2. @Override\n@param\n@SuppressWarnings']
```

Comment: This is definitely a lot simpler if the lines do start with `@`. Note that the lines starting `1.` etc may have spaces at the beginning based on OPs comments to my answer (see the changes I made in my edit).